# Undefined error when trying to identify descendant of parent using hasAttribute

Tags: javascript, touchmove, descendant

I'm trying to determine if an element is a descendant of another elect that has a specific attribute. So far, I have no issue when the value is true, but I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'node.hasAttribute(attribute)')` when hasAttribute is false. Any ideas?

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) { stopScroll(event); });
var stopScroll = function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    var parent = target.parentNode;

    if (isDescendantOf.attribute('data-scroll', target)) {

    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
};
var isDescendantOf = {};
isDescendantOf.parent = function(parent, child) {
    var node = child.parentNode;
    while (typeof node !== 'undefined') {
        if (node == parent) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
};
isDescendantOf.tag = function(tag, child) {
    var node = child.parentNode;
    while (typeof node !== 'undefined') {
        if (node.tagName == tag) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
};
isDescendantOf.attribute = function(attribute, child) {
    var node = child.parentNode;
    while (node !== null) {
        console.log(typeof node);
        if (node.hasAttribute(attribute) === true) {
            return true;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Here's the fiddle, though it acts even weirder for some reason: http://jsfiddle.net/x95tgmkn/

Comment: Try using parentElement or check the type of the node for text vs element

Comment: @Mouser I had tried doing that with `typeof node === 'object'` in the other functions, tried changing it to `node !== null` but still the same issue. Is there another way to check if it's an element?'

Comment: After a quick google, `node instanceof HTMLElement` appears to be the way to go. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Comment: Using parentElement ignores textnodes

Answer (score 0):

Your loop goes from the `child.parentNode` up to the [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.document), and on each `node` it uses the [`hasAttribute` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.hasAttribute) of the `Element` interface. However, [`Document`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) are plain `Node`s that do not implement this interface.

Change your condition to

```
while (node != null && node.nodeType == 1)
```

or `node.nodeType != 9` or `typeof node.hasAttribute == "function"`.